# Molecular Geometry of IF₄⁺

Tags: bond, vsepr-theory

Recently I came across a question asking for the geometry of the aforementioned molecule.
The answer key claimed the shape as an irregular tetrahedron, but as per my knowledge, it should have been like a see-saw.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes it is seasaw. The charge plays a apart so that may be the missing link.

Comment: apply hyrbridisation theory to see geometry of IF4